# Difference in behaviour between Perl versions

Tags: perl

I have the following script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
print "sample\n";
syswrite STDIN, "script";
my $input = <STDIN>;
print "$input";
```

This scripts executes properly in Perl 5.8.8 version giving the following output:

```
sample
script
```

However when executed in Perl 5.14.2 it gives the following error:

> Filehandle STDIN opened only for input at ./sample.pl line 5.

What has been changed between the Perl versions?

Comment: The idea that 5.8.8 allowing a write to Standard Input is "proper" execution, strikes me as funny.  In any case `perldoc perldelta` will give you a list of changes between the current version & the previous one.

Comment: I did check the perldoc perldelta. But it doesn't mention anything about STDIN or writing to STDIN. Any other pointers?

Comment: You should know that each perldelta only represents the changes between a single version and the one immediately previous.  For the complete story you'll need to read `perl589delta`, `perl5100delta`, perl5101delta` ....  Get comfy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, you're asking to replicate the 5.8.8 behaviour. I'm not sure how much sense makes to do so, but you can create a Perl read-write handle attached to the same file descriptor as follows:

```
$ perl -e'
   open(my $fh, "+>&=", 0) or die $!;
   print($fh "foo\n") or die $!;
' >/dev/null
foo
```

or

```
$ perl -e'
   {
      open(my $fh, "+>&=", 0) or die $!;
      close(STDIN);
      open(STDIN, "+>&=", $fh) or die $!;
   }
   print(STDIN "foo\n") or die $!;
' >/dev/null
foo
```

Comment: please give me the exact output of running the first snippet.